# Trouble with setting the Nest field values via java/android code

Tags: android, curl, nest-api

I am writing android code to change the field in a Nest thermostat using the newly released API. Authentication and getting the field values is working just perfect, however I am haing problem with *changing* the field values. Based on the the API for changing the field values you need to use HTTP put, but once I am doing this, nothing happens in the device (the value (e.g. the value of target_temperature_f doesn't change!))

Here is my android code:

```
    String url = "https://developer-api.nest.com/devices/thermostats/" 
            + this.device_id + "?auth=" + this.access_token;    
    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        /** set the proxy , not always needed  */
        HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(proxy_ip,proxy_port);
        httpclient.getParams().setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY,proxy);       

        // Set the new value
        HttpPut httpPut = new HttpPut(url);

        httpPut.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject("{\"target_temperature_f\":'60'}");
        HttpEntity put_entity =  new StringEntity(jsonObj.toString());
        httpPut.setEntity(put_entity);

        HttpResponse put_response = httpclient.execute(httpPut);
```

I can set the field in the device via "curl" command in linux though!!  So the device is working fine.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I'm unsure of how to do it using the [DefaultHttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html) and according to the documentation it has been deprecated in favor of [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html).

Here's some code that uses HttpURLConnection that I've tested with Hue lights.

This will open a URL connection and perform a POST query with the given body. The readFromHttpConnection method expects a JSON response. It looks like Nest uses JSON so this may work for your needs.

```
private String synchronousPostMethod(String destination, String body)
{
    Log.i(TAG, "Attempting HTTP POST method. Address=" + destination + "; Body=" + body);

    String responseReturn;

    try
    {
        HttpURLConnection httpConnection = openConnection(destination);
        httpConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        httpConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        writeToHttpConnection(httpConnection, body);

        responseReturn = readFromHttpConnection(httpConnection);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        responseReturn = RESPONSE_FAIL_MESSAGE + "; exception = " + e;
    }

    Log.i(TAG, "Result of HTTP POST method: " + responseReturn);

    return responseReturn;
}
```

These are the helper methods.

```
private HttpURLConnection openConnection(String destination)
{
    HttpURLConnection httpConnection = null;

    try
    {
        URL connectionUrl = new URL(destination);
        httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connectionUrl.openConnection();
    }
    catch(MalformedURLException malformedUrlException)
    {
        Log.w(TAG, "Failed to generate URL from malformed destination: " + destination);
        Log.w(TAG, "MalformedURLException = " + malformedUrlException);
    }
    catch(IOException ioException)
    {
        Log.w(TAG, "Could not open HTTP connection. IOException = " + ioException);
    }

    return httpConnection;
}

private boolean writeToHttpConnection(HttpURLConnection httpConnection, String data)
{
    // No data can be written if there is no connection or data
    if(httpConnection == null || data == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    try
    {
        OutputStreamWriter outputStream = new OutputStreamWriter(httpConnection.getOutputStream());
        outputStream.write(data);
        outputStream.close();
    }
    catch(IOException ioException)
    {
        Log.w(TAG, "Failed to get output stream from HttpUrlConnection. IOException = " + ioException);

        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

private String readFromHttpConnection(HttpURLConnection httpConnection)
{
    String responseReturn = "";

    if(httpConnection != null)
    {
        try
        {
            InputStream response = httpConnection.getInputStream();
            int size;

            do
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[mResponseBufferSize];
                size = response.read(buffer, 0, mResponseBufferSize);

                // Convert the response to a string then add it to the end of the buffer
                responseReturn += new String(buffer, 0, size);
            }while(size < mResponseBufferSize || size <= 0);

            // Cleanup
            response.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ioException)
        {
            Log.w(TAG, "Failed to get input stream from HttpUrlConnection. IOException = " + ioException);
        }
    }

    return responseReturn;
}
```

Comment: Tonyr, thanks a lot. I realized that the problem was due to "redirection". It is handled now so my code follows up the redirected url. The problem solved! Thanks for your comment though.